# Factor cubic polynomial into three linear factors, where each linear factor has a root as the constant term

Tags: polynomials

I have been working on an exercise in a book on polynomials. The question has three parts (a.), (b.), and (c.). We have a cubic polynomial $p(t)$ :
\begin{equation}
p(t) = at^{3} + bt^{2} + ct + d
\end{equation}
And we let $x,y,z$ be three zeroes of $p$. Part (a.) of the problem asks the reader to show that :
\begin{equation}
p(t) = p(t) - p(x) = (t-x)(at^{2} + (ax+b)t + (ax^{2} + bx + c))
\end{equation}
I was able to do this part.

The second part (part (b.)) asks the reader to show that $p(t)$ can be written in the form :
\begin{equation}
p(t) = a(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)
\end{equation}
This is the part I'm having trouble with. Does anyone have an idea as to how to show this ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $x,y,z$ are roots of $p$, then the polynomial $p(t)$ is divisible by $(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)$ (I think this is called the Factor Theorem).

Since both of the poly's in the last sentence are cubics, the quotient must be a (non-zero) constant, which, by looking at the leading coefficients (i.e. the coefficients of $t^3$), must be $a$.